# How can I get an instance of this particular Request?

Tags: php, laravel

## Errors I am getting:

Argument 1 passed to App\Services\Credit\CreditLoadUserService::index() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in C:\wamp64\www\dev\get-served-admin\app\Http\Controllers\CreditLoadUserController.php on line 30

## Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    view()->share('page_sub', 'List');
    $credit = CreditLoadUser::all();
    $data = $this->user_load_service->index($credit);
    return view('pages.user-loads.index')->with('credit', $data);
}
```

## Service Class:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return CreditLoadUser::where('user_id',$request->get('user_id'))
        ->where('is_loaded','<>',1)
        ->leftJoin('credit_load','credit_load.id','=','credit_load_id')
        ->orderBy('credit_load.valid_at')
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass Request to your services index method which you are not passing, better way is to use request helper method have look below code.

Service Class:

```
public function index()
{
    return CreditLoadUser::where('user_id',request()->get('user_id'))
        ->where('is_loaded','<>',1)
        ->leftJoin('credit_load','credit_load.id','=','credit_load_id')
        ->orderBy('credit_load.valid_at')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: I've tried but I get no return values. I am trying to put a mobile number data to a data table.

Answer (score 0):

The Request object will be injected automatically only to action methods in controllers.

Another point to note is that you should avoid writing HTTP aware code in your service layer. Consider situations that you want to use your service layer inside an artisan command or in a job, you haven't any request in the CLI context. So you should write this way:

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    view()->share('page_sub', 'List');
    $credit = CreditLoadUser::all();
    $data = $this->user_load_service->index($request->get('user_id'));
    return view('pages.user-loads.index')->with('credit', $data);
}
```

Service Class:

```
public function index($userId)
{
    return CreditLoadUser::where('user_id', $userId)
        ->where('is_loaded','<>',1)
        ->leftJoin('credit_load','credit_load.id','=','credit_load_id')
        ->orderBy('credit_load.valid_at')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting no return values. I am trying to fetch a user's mobile number to be put on a data table in my view. In my controller, can I bind the model on my route as a key for my $request variable/value?

Comment: If you have `id` of a model in the path of a route as a route variable, yes you can inject a model instance in your action. For example: ```Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) { return $user->email; });``` . But I am not sure about that if the `id` is in the request body or query string.

Comment: I am using a resource route for all my controllers. I believe the actions are all set up by that with their appropriate id's. I've tried binding the model instance though. I get the same error and I'm stuck. I tried everything I could. there seems to be a problem somewhere - I don't know.

Comment: In the sample code that you've provided in your question, you hadn't bound the model into the action's argument. If you tried different code then please provide your latest tried codes

Comment: It's okay I finally fixed it. Appreciate you trying to help. Have a good day!